# Programmatically set WearableActionDrawerView menu

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to set the menu (`actionMenu`) of a `WearableActionDrawerView` in code?

```
<android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableActionDrawerView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_action"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:actionMenu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These contextual actions may be specified by using a Menu, which may
>   be populated by either:
>
> Specifying the app:actionMenu attribute in the XML layout file.
>   Example:
>
> ```
>  <android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableActionDrawerView
>      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>      android:layout_width=”match_parent”
>      android:layout_height=”match_parent”
>      app:actionMenu="@menu/action_drawer" />
> ```
>
> Getting the menu with getMenu(), and then inflating it with
>   inflate(int, Menu). Example:
>
> ```
>  Menu menu = actionDrawer.getMenu();
>  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_drawer, menu);
> ```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/drawer/WearableActionDrawerView.html